24.10 /etc/crypttab is not unlocking drives on boot with 1000% working config
After doing a fresh install of 24.10 I ported over my config that I had that was working for years. This config was working fine on 22.04 b4 this. I only used nofail in the last colum.
/etc/crypttab
dm_crypt-0 UUID=1234 none luks

sea4tb  UUID=1234  /etc/luks-keys/sea4tb  luks,nofail,timeout=10s
wd4tb   UUID=1234  /etc/luks-keys/sea4tb  luks,nofail,timeout=10s
8tb     UUID=1234  /etc/luks-keys/sea4tb  luks,nofail,timeout=10s
2tb     UUID=1234  /etc/luks-keys/sea4tb  luks,nofail,timeout=10s
2tbb    UUID=1234  /etc/luks-keys/sea4tb  luks,nofail,timeout=10s

I deleted the /etc/luks-keys folder and used gnome-disks to recreate the folder and keyfile, so the permissions are 100% OK and that file also must not have a newline at the end. If you create it with nano you need an extra switch for it not to add a newline. I have experience with this. Obviously I use the same passphrase for all my drives.
And here comes the weird part and why I also not need to show you my fstab:
The configs actually work! When I boot Ubuntu up and open up gnome-disks all I need to do is click on the lock icon below my luks partitions, and they will be mounted instantly without getting ask for root password or luks passphrase so its actually working just not on boot.
What I already tried is remove the nofail from the two disks that are actually currently connected to my PC. Does not help.
I also tried sudo update-initramfs -u and sudo update-initramfs -c -k all because those came up when I searched around. I remember these commands being slower, they are basically instant now.
I also found out something I am not sure if I understand correctly, but it seems like since 2015 systemd has some feature that it actually can unlock multiple disks at boot without any keyfile if I get this right. Did not know about this and not sure how to use this yet. I also would like to know if this means the passphrase gets stored forever in the kernel keyring, so I can even after boot connect another disk and it will unlock.


The "ask-password" framework used to query for LUKS harddisk   passwords or SSL passwords during boot gained support for   caching
passwords in the kernel keyring, if it is   available. This makes sure
that the user only has to type in   a passphrase once if there are
multiple objects to unlock   with the same one. Previously, such
password caching was   available only when Plymouth was used; this
moves the   caching logic into the systemd codebase itself. The
"systemd-ask-password" utility gained a new --keyname=   switch to
control which kernel keyring key to use for   caching a password in.
This functionality is also useful for   enabling display managers such
as gdm to automatically   unlock the user's GNOME keyring if its
passphrase, the   user's password and the harddisk password are the
same, if   gdm-autologin is used.


How would I use this? I tried putting none instead of the keyfile path but did not work, but I think I forgot to umdate-initramfs if this is needed.
Then there is /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook
#
# Configuration file for the cryptroot initramfs hook.
#

#
# KEYFILE_PATTERN: ...
#
# The value of this variable is interpreted as a shell pattern.
# Matching key files from the crypttab(5) are included in the initramfs
# image.  The associated devices can then be unlocked without manual
# intervention.  (For instance if /etc/crypttab lists two key files
# /etc/keys/{root,swap}.key, you can set KEYFILE_PATTERN="/etc/keys/*.key"
# to add them to the initrd.)
#
# If KEYFILE_PATTERN if null or unset (default) then no key file is
# copied to the initramfs image.
#
# Note that the glob(7) is not expanded for crypttab(5) entries with a
# 'keyscript=' option.  In that case, the field is not treated as a file
# name but given as argument to the keyscript.
#
# WARNING:
# * If the initramfs image is to include private key material, you'll
#   want to create it with a restrictive umask in order to keep
#   non-privileged users at bay.  For instance, set UMASK=0077 in
#   /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
# * If you use cryptsetup-suspend, private key material inside the
#   initramfs will be in memory during suspend period, defeating the
#   purpose of cryptsetup-suspend.
#

#KEYFILE_PATTERN=

#
# ASKPASS: [ y | n ]
#
# Whether to include the askpass binary to the initramfs image.  askpass
# is required for interactive passphrase prompts, and ASKPASS=y (the
# default) is implied when the hook detects that same device needs to be
# unlocked interactively (i.e., not via keyfile nor keyscript) at
# initramfs stage.  Setting ASKPASS=n also skips `cryptroot-unlock`
# inclusion as it requires the askpass executable.

#ASKPASS=y

I do have a default setup where /boot is unencrypted, and my root partition is still an LV with just a single ext4 inside it for whatever reason. So when I get asked for the password in unlocks the Ubuntu main and only partition and has access to /etc/luks-keys so not sure if something has changed here, but it seems to me there is no need to copy these over into a ramdisk but maybe that is what I need? Has this changed? It's less secure to have these always sit in the ram but not really an issue as I consider my system compromised if someone gets physical access anyway.
ASKPASS=y seems to be the default anyway, and I am in fact asked for the pass, it just seems not to be used for the other disks and the keyfile does not seem to be read on boot. Again this all worked fine in 22.04 without any other changes that I remember doing.

Take a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/2084251.
Installing systemd-cryptsetup fixed the issue for me.
sudo apt-get install systemd-cryptsetup


This was it. That bug states its only about upgrading Ubuntu or using ZFS, neither is the case for me. I have a clean installation and no ZFS. Anything except the main partition does not get mounted without that package.
